# How to select all observations whose name starts with a specific element in python

Tags: python, string, object, startswith

I have a dataframe where I want to create a Dummy variable that takes the value 1 when the Asset Class starts with a D. I want to have all variants that start with a D. How would you do it?

The data looks like

```
dic = {'Asset Class':  ['D.1', 'D.12', 'D.34','nan', 'F.3', 'G.12', 'D.2', 'nan']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

What I want to have is

```
dic_want = {'Asset Class':  ['D.1', 'D.12', 'D.34', 'nan', 'F.3', 'G.12', 'D.2', 'nan'],
            'Asset Dummy':  [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]}
df_want = pd.DataFrame(dic_want)
```

I tried

```
df_want["Asset Dummy"] = ((df["Asset Class"] == df.filter(like="D"))).astype(int)
```

where I get the following error message: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

I also tried

```
CSDB["test"] = ((CSDB["PAC2"] == CSDB.str.startswith('D'))).astype(int)
```

where I get the error message AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'.
I tried to transform my object to a string with the standard methos (as.typ(str) and to_string()) but it also does not work. This is probably another problem but I have found only one post with the same question but the post does not have a satisfactory answer.

Any ideas how I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.str.startswith` on `df['Asset Class']`:

```
>>> dic = {'Asset Class':  ['D.1', 'D.12', 'D.34', 'nan', 'F.3', 'G.12', 'D.2', 'nan']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
>>> df['Asset Dummy'] = df['Asset Class'].str.startswith('D').astype(int)
>>> df
  Asset Class  Asset Dummy
0         D.1            1
1        D.12            1
2        D.34            1
3         nan            0
4         F.3            0
5        G.12            0
6         D.2            1
7         nan            0
```

Comment: If I do that I get the error message ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer. How would you integrate missing values in the code?

Comment: @Lisa missing values? Where is this in the question? Please edit the question to include this case and its expected output.

Comment: I added them to the question.

Comment: @Lisa What is the problem? The output is still correct, `0` for `nan` since `nan` doesn't start with `D`.

Comment: I still get the same error message ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create a new column based on conditions this is one of them :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dic = {'Asset Class':  ['D.1', 'D.12', 'D.34', 'F.3', 'G.12', 'D.2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

df['Dummy'] = np.where(df['Asset Class'].str.contains("D"), 1, 0)
```

Here's a link to more : https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-add-column-pandas-dataframe-based-on-if-else-condition/

Comment: The code almost works! However, I also get a 1 for missing values? How is this possible?